# Extract Excel data to transform to a simple XML

Tags: excel, mule, datamapper

I am working on creating orders/receipts for a certain client that provides the data using Excel. However, it is not a common Excel table format but an actual form to be printed. I am having issues with the data mapper since it cannot be parsed correctly.

Is there a way to get the data so I can transform it to a simple XML?

I'm thinking if I can just get the data by declaring which column/row.

[image]

Comment: yes, it is received as excel file as is as this is is formatted to be printed for manual processing.I need to process it to be able to be automatically processed in our system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to use a custom transformer using *Apache POI* from XLS to a simple java POJO, then you can get your XML using the object-to-xml-transformer.

apache POI: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

object-to-xml-transformer:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/xmlobject-transformers